# problems with converting string which contains xml code into XmlTextWriter

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xmltextwriter

I have a `string` variable `Writer` that recieves xml code from another `window`. I need to pass this `string` to `textWriter` variable but i dont know how to make it readable by `textWriter`. I tried to convert it to `XmlTextWriter` but it dont seem to work. How can it be accepted by `textWriter`?

```cs
textWriter = (XmlTextWriter)XmlTextWriter.Create(new StringBuilder(Writer));
```

```cs
XmlTextWriter textWriter; 

public Question_Redactor(int k, string Writer)
{          
    textWriter =  new XmlTextWriter(Writer);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

When the code runs, the following error message is generated:

> The system.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast objects of type"
> System. Xml. XmlWellFormedWriter "to type" System. Xml.
> XmlTextWriter"."

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, there  is:
`The system.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast objects of type" System. Xml. XmlWellFormedWriter "to type" System. Xml. XmlTextWriter"."`

Comment: Use following :             StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("string");
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder);

Answer (score 1):

Did like [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) suggested and it worked perfectly

```
XmlWriter testWriter; 

        public Question_Redactor(int k, string Writer)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(Writer);
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder);
            testWriter = writer;

            InitializeComponent();

          
        }
```